# How can I load only the factories that this page requires from a dependency injection container

Tags: php, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I'm working on upgrading the framework of my web application to use a dependency injection container and I'm trying to make sure I do it right. The container is setup to build a number of factories used by other classes for getting site resources, these could be clients or payment histories or any number of things so there are going to be a fair few factories.

Now I could have a resource manager class sit at the top that has an instance of each kind of factory but not every page is going to use every factory. Each page is likely to only need one or two factories so loading every factory for every page is going to cause unnecessary slowdown. So I need a way of each page getting only the resources it needs.

Should I:

1. Have a factory factory that can be loaded on every page that lazy loads specific factories as they are requested.
2. Register each page in the container so that it's dependencies are managed by the root of the application as the page is requested. (seems like the container would get huge as each page would require a new entry, this solution seems elegant but would increase the development cost of creating a new page)
3. Pass the container to each page so that it can load the dependencies it wants as it needs them at runtime. (really not sure about this, seems like the simplest solution but would have to make sure that the container doesn't go any further into the application, also if there are 100's of pages then you now have 100's of places where your container is used instead of just 1 at the root)
4. An obviously better solution that I haven't thought of because I'm a noob...

Comment: Ok so after a bit more thought I've decided to go with option 2. I'm using symfony's dependency injection container and it allows you to separate the definitions into many files. So each page will have a companion file for the dependency injection container outlining it's requirements. This way the number of pages wont affect the container's load time as it won't load the definitions of the pages it isn't using and every page will have exactly what it needs.

Comment: It would help if you tell us which language / web framework you are using since these kind of solutions tend to be framework specific.

Comment: Yeah it's php and the framework is one I'm making myself so it was more of a design question. I should have mentioned that it's php as compiled languages wouldn't need to organise all the resources and load the dependency injection definition for each http request. All good though option 2 is working out well.